# Tell a configure script to use a relative path for --datarootdir

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf

I have used GNU autoconf to generate a configure script for a program of mine, which I am now trying to cross-compile for Windows.

Under Linux, to change the location of the data files I supply `--datarootdir=/blah` which works fine. Under Windows however, my application's path won't be known until run time (as the user could choose to install it anywhere.)  Therefore I want to set the data directory to be the current directory, wherever that may be at the time the application is launched.

Unfortunately, passing `--datarootdir=.` doesn't work:

```
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --datarootdir: .
```

How do you tell Autoconf/configure that you *want* a path relative to the current directory at run time?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found a partial solution for this.  It seems `--datarootdir` is used to control where the files are *installed* to, so it needs to be an absolute path for the benefit of `make install`.  However it can be overridden during compilation:

```
make datadir="."
```

This way, during compilation the code thinks the `$(datadir)` is "." but when running `make install` the files are still placed in the absolute path given to `./configure --datarootdir=...`

Comment: Of course I have since realised that this isn't the best solution either.  When launching the .exe directly it works fine (.exe is in the current directory), but when double-clicking on a document file associated with the app, the .exe is launched from the document file's directory, which means the data files cannot be found...

Answer (score 1):

Just give it an absolute path that is equal to the current working directory:

```
./configure --datarootdir=$PWD
```

Comment: The problem there is that if one user chooses to install my app on the target system into C:\Program Files, and another into D:\Apps, the datarootdir will be different between the two.  $PWD will only be accurate at compile time, whereas I need the value to be relative to the run time current directory.